Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o71.parquet
I get this error while running pyspark, my configuration is as follow:
Python 3.10
PySpark 3.5.1
JDK 10.0.2
Spark-shell 3.5.1
my code:
`   import os
    os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = r"C:\Users\GGGT\Jupyter\Spark"
    os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = 'python'
    os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = 'jupyter'
    os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS'] = 'notebook'
    import pyspark
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("PySaprk_Init") \
        .getOrCreate()

    import math
    import geocoder

    from geopy.distance import geodesic

    from functools import partial
    import pyproj

    import shapely
    from shapely import geometry
    from shapely.geometry import Point
    from shapely.ops import transform
    from shapely import wkt



    from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType,StringType, BooleanType
    import pyspark.sql.types as Types
    from pyspark.sql.window import Window
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
    import pyspark.pandas as ps
    from pyspark import SparkConf
    import pyspark
    import socket
    def spark_shape(self):
        return (self.count(), len(self.columns))
    
    pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.shape = spark_shape

    @F.udf(returnType=FloatType())
    def geodesic_udf(a, b):
        # Returns the distance in meters between 2 coordinates
        return geodesic(a, b).m

    @F.udf(returnType=Types.ArrayType(Types.StringType()))
    def get_latlon(address):
        g = geocoder.bing(address,key='AusbE57ZoeXHwoYajOKz13DmF5OsMi5eAwyrFHLaeG8yMVtUIQuTDbwTVSjKrwig')
        results = g.json
        return results['lat'],results['lng']

    dfCSV = spark.read.csv("barn/Locations.csv", header=True,mode="DRPMALFORMED")
    dfLatLon = dfCSV.select(['LOCATION_CODE','Location ID','COUNTY','Address','Address: Street-1','Address: Street 2','Address: City','Address: State/Region','Address: Postal Code'])\
        .where(F.col('Address: Street 1').isNotNull())
    dfLatLon = dfLatLon.withColumn('Lat',get_latlon(F.col('Address'))[0])\
        .withColumn('Long',get_latlon(F.col('Address'))[1])
    dfLatLon.show()

    df_is = spark.read.parquet('zonar/tables/idle_stop')`

I get the following error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o71.parquet.
: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
